# Is calling python script for many kinds of operations from rails, on heroku, a good idea?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, tensorflow, machine-learning

What are the pros and cons of using Rails but using python scripts for all kinds of operations, including ML (hosting on heroku)? I like Rails, but if Django would be better long-term, I'm willing to switch to that.

I'm hoping that by framing this question as "pros and cons," this fits more into stack overflow norm... if not, I'm sorry. I'd really appreciate help though.

Comment: IMO no point in doing that, just use Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I like rails, but...

What do you like about rails? Rails is great, but what does it offer that Django does not? It's quite common to have multiple languages in one project, multiple languages are complied to the same code. There are libraries like 'rupy' that make it a simple thing to do, if you are more comfortable with rails than django then there is a use case to consider the proposed approach. There are some issues in general, the main will be around what is 'best' architecturally.

In regard to any possible cons, let's try to explore any that may come up when modelling a real-world example:

```
def init_py_script
  parsed_output = JSON.parse(`cat #{file.path} | python3 lib/some_python_script.py`)
end
```

Why did the author chose to do this? In our model, let's say they outsourced the work the python code is doing due to not understanding how to complete the task in ruby. Maybe they did not have the bandwidth to learn how to do this in ruby and could only find a python developer who could complete the work.

Which is fine, but there some issues here. [Note these issues may/may not apply to you]:

1. The user has to install different dependencies on their server in order to run both languages, which takes time to understand and debug.
2. If the outsourced coder uploads the code to another repository; most deployment scripts won't be able to deploy the submodule code and there is manual intervention required.
3. Maintaining multiple languages on a server is not easy and when upgrading packages, which may cause issues such as having to install multiple 'libssl-dev' packages, which creates more ongoing work.
4. Ruby and rails is classically driven by TDD. If you solely rely on unit tests, there will be no issue. If you like to incorporate integration tests, it will be much harder to get full coverage.
5. When writing code, the author should be conscientious of the reader and reducing the cognitive load of future readers and developers to understand what applications are doing. You'll restrict the amount of developers who can work on the entire project going forward if you include more languages as they will have to understand both languages. This may not be an issue if they are working on one small component of the application.

TLDR: It's OK for small projects. Using multiple languages causes infrastructure issues by likely cause version conflicts in the future. Upgrading will likely be more difficult. If you have good documentation and tests, the development of code should remain unaffected.